# YOCTO : No '/lib/modules' directory in image, modprobe fails

Tags: module, embedded-linux, yocto

I'm trying to load and unload modules using **modprobe** but I'm having problems.  The command fails with "modprobe:

> can't change directory to '/lib/modules': no such file or directory"

There is actually no */lib/modules* directory on the image at all.

PS : I used **yocto project** to build Linux os image and I'm using the **3.14 kernel**.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you just don't have any modules installed. Add

> IMAGE_INSTALL += "kernel-modules"

to your image recipe.

Update:
If this does not add the modules to the image, your next steps to check are:

1. Check if there actually any modules built. Not all kernel configurations actually do this. An easy way is to look into the `tmp/deploy/...` directory that holds your generated packages.
2. Check if the setting actually gets propagated to the iamge. `bitbake -e` on your image will tell, grep for IMAGE_INSTALL.

Update 2:

For 1) All built kernel-modules are automatically packaged in packages starting with "kernel-module-". So if there is no package bearing that prefix and the module name you expect, then its not a problem of installing, but a problem of your kernel or kernel config not building the module at all.

For 2) "I can't read it all": Thats why I explicitly said "grep for IMAGE_INSTALL" - you shall not read it all, just see if that variable actually includes "kernel-modules".

Comment: I added this to local.conf file and i rebuild the image but same problem occures !

Comment: This did not help me. Under tmp/deploy i can find generated image and what packages installed not modules. Besides the result of bitbake -e is long list that i can't read it all

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution:
In fact

> IMAGE_INSTALL += "kernel-modules"

Does not add modules folder under */lib* . It does not work wiTh YOCTO PROJECT **SUMO** release. I added this

> CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " kernel-modules"

to my local.conf and now the */lib/modules* is found and kernel-modules are packaged

Comment: No, one more time you failed to read properly. I specifically wrote: "add to your image recipe", and there it would have worked instantly. CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL is only needed for going through local.conf, AND it is NOT a generic way that works for all images. So while I think this answer should be kept for reference, it proposes a wreong approach for reproductibly building images, as it relies on local.conf.

Comment: @LetoThe2nd That is my bad. Thank you for your support. I will try again with adding IMAGE_INSTALL += "kernel-modules" to the image-recipe